# jQuery on change of input field, change value in respective element

Tags: jquery

I need the value in the  elements to change when the "respective" text input is changed. By "respective" I mean the span that has the same classname as the input's ID, plus "txt-".

So if the value of `<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />` changes, that value needs to be copied into the txt-firstname span:

```
<span class="txt-firstname">First Name</span>
```

This works but only for the first one. I know I need some kind of a loop, but I just can't figure it out:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var divID = $('.obituary-form input[type=text]').attr("id");
       $("#" + divID).change(function() {
            $(".txt-" + divID).text(this.value); 
        });
     });    
 });
</script>        

<div class="obituary-form">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />    
    <input type="text" name="cityofresidence" id="cityofresidence" />
</div>

<div>
    <span class="txt-firstname">First Name</span>
     <span class="txt-middlename">Middle Name</span>
    <span class="txt-lastname">Last Name</span>
    <span class="txt-cityofresidence">City of residence</span>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loop needed. Simply use the ID of the input when changing it:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  $(".txt-" + this.id).text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="obituary-form">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
  <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
  <input type="text" name="cityofresidence" id="cityofresidence" />
</div>

<div>
  <span class="txt-firstname">First Name</span>
  <span class="txt-middlename">Middle Name</span>
  <span class="txt-lastname">Last Name</span>
  <span class="txt-cityofresidence">City of residence</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only going to get one `id`:

```
var divID = $('.obituary-form input[type=text]').attr("id");
```

So your next statement will only end up binding one element.  Instead of trying to loop through the elements, start with a selector which targets your elements and bind to those:

```
$('.obituary-form input[type=text]').change(function() {
    // handle the change event
});
```

This will bind to each matching element, regardless of how many there are.  Now, *within* that handler, you need to get the `id` of `this` (in the context of the executing handler) and use that to match your target.  Perhaps something like this:

```
$('.obituary-form input[type=text]').change(function() {
    let self = $(this);
    $('.txt-' + self.prop('id')).text(self.val());
});
```

Or maybe even:

```
$('.obituary-form input[type=text]').change(function() {
    $('.txt-' + this.id).text(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("change","#" + divID,function(e){
    $(".txt-" + divID).text(this.value); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
       $('input:text').change(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr('name');
            $('.txt-'+name).text($(this).val()); 
        })
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="obituary-form">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="middlename" id="middlename" />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />    
    <input type="text" name="cityofresidence" id="cityofresidence" />
</div>

<div>
    <span class="txt-firstname">First Name</span>
     <span class="txt-middlename">Middle Name</span>
    <span class="txt-lastname">Last Name</span>
    <span class="txt-cityofresidence">City of residence</span>      
</div>
```